# Table formulation in Mixed Integer Programming

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, mixed-integer-programming

I have a mixed integer non-linear optimisation problem. The non-linearity comes from a non-linear equation in which the optimisation variable, $N$, is coupled with another variable that is not optimisation variable, $\tau$, but it is in the objective function.

Therefore, the way I was thinking about to remove the non-linearity is to make a table for different value of $N$ and $\tau$. If I do so, the next step would be formulating the table for different values of $N$ in the problem. Is there any way to formulate the table? Or does anyone have any idea to solve this non-linear optimisation problem?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "is not optimisation variable"? If $\tau$ is not a variable, then it is a parameter (constant). Is the nonlinearity due to a product of $N$ and $\tau$, or something else?

Comment: The non-linearity comes from this equation: $(1-\tau)^N+N\tau-1=0$. Here, N is the optimization parameter, while $\tau$ is just a value which should be find. If this equation is solved, this parameter will be ignored in the problem. I have to linearize this equation or find a table for different $\tau$ and $N$.

Comment: If $\tau$ does not appear anywhere else in the problem besides this equation, why not just solve the rest of the problem for $N$ and set $\tau = 0$?

Comment: This $\tau$ shows up in the objective function. I mean this parameter in dependent on $N$. The best choice is to find $\tau$ as a function of $N$ to get rid of it. But because of the non-linearity nature of the equation, it seems impossible.

Comment: If $\tau$ is dependent on $N$ and $N$ is a variable, then $\tau$ is a variable, not a parameter.